# EnableDecompression for WCF - services?

Tags: wcf, http-compression

This is a major issue for me. In earlier times, web service clients could simply use EnableDecompression = true and all was good, but why did Microsoft not add something similar to WCF?

I really NEED gzip compressed responses from my WCF services (and they need to be http... legacy issues, as usual... you know...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/ramon/archive/2008/11/06/wcf-and-http-gzip-deflate-compression-and-silverlight.aspx) which basically ends up suggesting:

> **Conclusion**
>
> I now ditched this as we also need to
>   support clients that do not set the
>   AcceptEncoding header so I really need
>   the ability to read the http header in
>   request and set a "context" value to
>   (not) compress the response and I have
>   not found out yet how to do that per
>   multiple concurrent requests. **I really
>   recommend to use the IIS http
>   compression and not try to do this
>   with WCF hacking as described here!**

There's also a WCF Extensions project on Codeplex which has a [WCF Compression Channel](http://wcfextensions.codeplex.com/) - maybe that'll be what you're looking for.

The most bang for the buck would be to use the `binaryMessageEncoding` in WCF instead of the textMessageEncoding (which is the default for HTTP bindings). That would require you to [create a custom http based binding](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/02/22/WCF-Enable-Binary-Encoding-Over-Http.aspx), and would render your service incompatible with other http-based clients other than .NET clients that are also using the same custom binding configuration.

Comment: thank you, a very good link!

btw, I have issued a recommendation to switch to .NET 4.0 now, in .NET 4.0 everything works like a charm.